sqlalchemy orm selectinload not working at the get-all level
This is driving me crazy.  As an example, I have a many-to-many relationship between tables called labels and tasks. Take this code excerpt for a filtered record:
      statement = select(Label).filter(Label.id == label_id).options(selectinload(Label.tasks))
      result = await async_session.execute(statement)

      label = result.scalars().first()
      return label

This works great and I get a result that includes tasks like:
{
  "name": "string",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": "1ed56356-3f50-4630-be01-7aae9abc9f8f",
      "title": "string"
    }
  ]
}

But take this example:
      statement = 
      select(Label).order_by(Label.id).options(selectinload(Label.tasks))
      result = await async_session.execute(statement)
      labels = result.scalars()

      return labels

This gives me an output that is missing "tasks":
[
  {
    "name": "string",
  }
]

Why are there no "tasks" provided in this output? Shouldn't there be a "tasks: []" parameter like in the first output? I'm missing something dumb here I think :) Any idea what's going on?
Thanks,
Jon

May we assume that those two code snippits are from two separate routes, the first being @app.get("/labels/{label_id}", response_model=schemas.Label) and the second being @app.get("/labels/", response_model=List[schemas.Label]) ?

@GordThompson Yes, sorry. That's exactly right.  And for the first one I'm using a response model of "response_model=List[LabelModel]".  So that gets me thinking.  The LabelModel doesn't include tasks because it's part of a one-to-many relationship.  Let me see if changing the response model fixes this.  Thanks again for your help.

@GordThompson The response_model is definitely the issue.  I looped through labels before returning them and the tasks are there.  But the LabelModel doesn't have tasks in the model so it's not returning it.  So I just need to figure out how I can get it to return a different model that allows tasks.  Thanks for your question because that led me to the answer.

Many thanks to @GordThompson for leading me to the answer on this. The response_model for my router get-all endpoint was:
response_model=List[LabelModel],
This model didn't have a tasks parameter.  Because of that it wasn't adding the tasks in the response even though my label service was returning the tasks. So I created a new model that included the tasks model and changed the response model to:
response_model=List[LabelModelWithTask],
Now the response gives me all the labels back and in each label, I have a list of tasks being returned.
Hope this can help anyone else out with this issue.
